# Redirect from /en/page.html to page.html

Tags: magento-1.9, url, redirect, sitemaps, redirect-url

How can I automatically redirect custom pages from this URL

```
site.com/en/page.html
```

to this URL

```
site.com/page.html
```

In order to avoid problems with Google Search Console?

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to change some configuration on your Magento admin.

```
System > Configuration > General > Web > Url Options >  Add Store Code to Urls = No
```

It'll remove store codefrom url. I hop it'll help you for what you want.